# Swift waiting for page load from javascript in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview

I am attempting to log into a page using a UIWebView. Due to how complicated the infrastructure is, I'm loading the login page and manually submitting the form (inserting javascript). Once the home page is loaded, I want to redirect to another page. The only problem is that there is nothing I can do to have that redirect wait until the home page is loaded (Because I didn't load the view I submitted a form). Is there a way I can get it to wait?

My code currently

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(jScript3) //submit the form

let gradeURL = NSURL(string: "https://redirectpage")!
let gradeRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:gradeURL)
webView.loadRequest(gradeRequest)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think u may want get something from the redirect page.

First set the Delegate and then use UIwebViewDelegate funcion

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

    //do nothing except 4 the redirectURL
    if request.URL?.absoluteString.hasPrefix(redirectURL) == false  {
        return true
    }
    //detailly handle the query
    if let _query = request.URL?.query where _query.condition {...}
}
```

Comment: Dont force unwrap optionals. Use if let combined with ? To safely unwrap the URL or one of its properties. Also you should mention that he needs to make the view controller the webview delegate inside viewDidLoad

Comment: I was thinking it was logically could be nil here,but I agreed with force unwrap optionals always be a bad ideal,so I fixed it.